# Execute a safe SQL SELECT statement using raw SQL and no parameters

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'd like a method like this:

```
def executeSafeSqlSelect(projection, tables, where_clauses)
```

The where_clauses is a list of "WHERE" clauses that should never run any commands that could do anything other than filter results. I'm using pymysql. Is there a safe and simple way to do this without needing any ORM library and without needing to parameterize values separately?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid ORM libraries? You might be able to get away with rejecting anything containing other SQL keywords, though that would cause issues if anyone happened to be looking for something that happens to be valid SQL. Much beyond that, and you'd start to get into building your own library.

Comment: I looked at SQLAlchemy but even this seems to add more complexity than I want unless there is some simple way I can do above. Is there any library you can recommend/sample that can do something like this without needing to pull in a lot of extra concepts?

Comment: When you looked at SQLAlchemy did you look at SQLAlchemy Core? That includes the safe query-building and support for different dialects but mostly avoids building a bunch on top of that.

Comment: Hm. I see you can use text() construct but my complaint with this is that you need to keep track of what variables to later pass to the execute statement. This is what I'm trying to avoid so that you can't introduce an error by adding some variable in one place but not adding it in execute. It's not too big a deal but would be nice to have the clauses contain everything they need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may not be any really simple way, but an OK option is to make a separate helper class where you can add clauses that contain both the statement and parameters and then before calling execute() the helper class loops through all the clauses to build up the full statement and the full dictionary of parameters.

And for cases of equality you can provide a helper function like:

```
def append_where_equal(self, column_name, val): 
   self.append_where_clause_and_vars("{}=%({})s".
      format(column_name, column_name), {column_name: val})
```

In any case I would recommend also using something like SQLAlchemy Core as mentioned by @EFT.